# Duplicate WCF service calls being saved in database

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, duplicate-data

We have a C# WCF service (3.0) that takes in data and then make another web service call to a third party with that same data.

Before the third party call, the entry data is saved as a record in a database, and then updated with response data from the thrid party web service.

We have start doing some Load/Stress testing, and noticed that duplicate records in the database are being saved (which includes a randomly generated alphanumeric value); 2 or 3 at a time. Yet, when we check the third party service data, they are being logged on their side as seperate entries.

The only database fields that are different on our side is the "LastModifiedDate" which are within milliseconds from each other.

Any ideas what would be calling this behavior? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your randomly generated alphanumeric value isn't unique enough. Try adding an IDENTITY column or using a GUID.